# rosdoc_lite and missing raw_text support?

Tags: ros, ros-hydro, ros-groovy, rosdoc-lite

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I do

```
git clone https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite.git
```

I get a file msgenator.py that contains support for raw_text. But the msgenator file in the groovy and hydro debs does not contain that change. So what is wrong here? Is it me that uses the wrong rosdoc_lite?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/69640/rosdoc_lite-and-missing-raw_text-support?/) by [TommyP](https://answers.ros.org/users/1110/tommyp/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1339 on 2013-07-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The fix for this [issue (#29)](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rosdoc_lite/issues/29) has not been released yet.

A new rosdoc_lite release should be available soon.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2013-07-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0